# Nested if(e.getActionCommand().equals("")

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Can someone tell me if it is possible to nest the

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("some String"){//do it}
```

For example. . . .

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  theFrame.hide();

  if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Button in theFrame"))
  {
      newFramerz.show();

      if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Button in newFramerz"))
      {
       //do usual stuff
      }
  }
}
```

For some reason, my code was not working when I tried to compile it. Then I suspected the line of code which I've written at the topmost part.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible? An explaination would also be great.

**EDIT**

Here's a sample code of my problem.

```
public void ATM_MainMenu()
{

    //-----------------------------//
    MainMenu = new JFrame("Main Menu");

    JPanel TextPanel     = new JPanel();
    JPanel BTPanel       = new JPanel();
    JPanel FormPanel     = new JPanel();

    JLabel TextLabel     = new JLabel("Choose Transaction");

    JButton InquireBalBT = new JButton("Inquire Balance");
    InquireBalBT.addActionListener(this);
    JButton DepositBT    = new JButton("Deposit");
    DepositBT.addActionListener(this);
    JButton WithdrawBT   = new JButton("Withdraw");
    WithdrawBT.addActionListener(this);

    TextPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    TextPanel.add(TextLabel);
    BTPanel.add(TextPanel);
    BTPanel.add(InquireBalBT);
    BTPanel.add(DepositBT);
    BTPanel.add(WithdrawBT);
    FormPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    FormPanel.add(TextPanel);
    FormPanel.add(BTPanel);

    MainMenu.setContentPane(FormPanel);
    MainMenu.pack();
    MainMenu.show();
    MainMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    MainMenu.setResizable(false);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{     
    MainMenu.hide();

    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Inquire Balance") || e.getActionCommand().equals("Withdraw") || e.getActionCommand().equals("Deposit"))
    {
        //----------------------------------//

        PINEnter = new JFrame("PIN");

        JPanel PINTextPanel   = new JPanel();
        JPanel PINButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel PINUniterPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel PINTextLabel   = new JLabel("Please Enter PIN");

        JTextField PINField   = new JTextField(4); 

        JButton SubmitBT   = new JButton("Submit PIN");
        SubmitBT.addActionListener(this);

        PINTextPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        PINTextPanel.add(PINTextLabel);
        PINTextPanel.add(PINField);
        PINButtonPanel.add(SubmitBT);
        PINUniterPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        PINUniterPanel.add(PINTextPanel);
        PINUniterPanel.add(PINButtonPanel);

        PINEnter.setContentPane(PINUniterPanel);
        PINEnter.setSize(360,140);
        PINEnter.pack();
        PINEnter.show();
        PINEnter.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PINEnter.setResizable(false);

        PINNow =  PINField.getText();

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Inquire Balance")){OPTIONS = 1;}
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Withdraw")){OPTIONS = 3;}
        else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Deposit")){OPTIONS = 2;}

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Submit PIN") && PINNow.equals(RealPin))
        { // switch and then some functions which are too long}
}
}
}
```

This is the code I'm working on, an ATM-Simulator. The only problem is when I get to PINEnter and then I would press the SubmitBT, It would not go to the other frames. PINEnter had a JTextField PINField and I should convert the content into a String PIN. In order to go to the other frames, PIN should be equal to String RealPin which is "1234". So if the Submit PIN button and PIN is equal to RealPin then it should be going on already with the other functions. I expected that when SubmitBT is pressed, with the PIN the same as RealPIN I should be going to the if statements but then, It didn't.

Comment: Did you note you never closed your `(` of the if statement?
Can you be more specific on "not working when I tried to compile it".  Was it not compiling at all? If so, please give us the error.
Or was it not running as you expected, then describe what you get and what you expected.

Comment: Oh, my bad.

I will try to edit and put another sample code about my problem.

Answer (score 2):

While syntactically you can do it - and it will compile, I don't think it will do what you're looking for.  Let's look at your code:

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Button in theFrame"))
{
    newFramerz.show();

    // If you got in here, then the value of e.getActionCommand() is "Button in theFrame"

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Button in newFramerz"))
    {
        //The execution will never get here, because
        //the value of e.getActionCommand() is "Button in theFrame"
        //and hence will never be equal to "Button in newFramerz"
    }
}
```

A more appropriate way of dealing with it would be:

```
String action = e.getActionCommand();

if(action.equals("Button in theFrame"))
{
    newFramerz.show();
    //whatever else
}
else if(action.equals("Button is newFramerz"))
{
    //do something else
}
```